# Showing bar plot side by side for two variables in dataframe

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a dataframe shown below:

```
structure(list(Age_group = c("0-1", "16-40", "2-5", "6-15", "Others"
), Ratio_no_V_tour = c(0.144814506265842, 0.368098268252477, 
0.135597426307673, 0.291277451831895, 0.0602123473421132), Ratio_V_tour = c(0.0704375667022412, 
0.431100508506498, 0.12103710214075, 0.302278862452131, 0.0751459601983803
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

  Age_group Ratio_no_V_tour Ratio_V_tour
  <chr>               <dbl>        <dbl>
1 0-1                0.145        0.0704
2 16-40              0.368        0.431 
3 2-5                0.136        0.121 
4 6-15               0.291        0.302 
5 Others             0.0602       0.0751
```

I am wodnering how I can plot a bar plot for column **Ratio_no_V_tour** and **Ratio_V_tour** for each **Age_group**. I looked into some solutions like this one https://dk81.github.io/dkmathstats_site/rvisual-sidebyside-bar.html ; however, in the example shown in the link, the two-column has the same name. I can do the same here manually, but I am more looking into smarter solution to plot this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `base R` `barplot`

```
barplot(t(`row.names<-`(as.matrix(df1[-1]), df1$Age_group)),
      legend = TRUE, beside = TRUE)
```

-output

[image]

---

Or if we wanted to use `ggplot`, reshape to 'long' format

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Age_group) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Age_group, y = value, fill = name)) +
      geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
      theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to show them side by side? Also, can we use `ggplot` so we have more flexibility in working with graphs?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I guess my problem was with changing the wide table to long which you solved it by using `pivot_longer`. thanks